# Extracting data from SQLite

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, nonblocking, web-sql

I have a problem and no idea how to solve it.

I'm working on a small web application. In the application there is a posting system
where the users can post articles. Now, when the user logs in, I save
his email (which is unique to every user) in the SQLite database and when the user adds a post, I send all the data from the 'post form' and his email to the server (Then I save it in mongoDB). The problem is that the email is always undefined. Here are the relevant parts of the code:

### Extracting the data from the DB

```
function extractDetalisFromDB(){
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}


// Extracting the relevant data - there is always only one user in the db, hence the 'id=1'
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM currentUser WHERE id=1', [], querySuccess, onError);
}


function querySuccess(tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length;
   currentUserName = results.rows.item(0).name;
   currentUserEmail = results.rows.item(0).data;
}
```

*currentUserName and currentUserEmail are global variables.*

### Validating and Posting the form

```
function validateNewPost() {
    // Here I validate the data from the form... works well.

    if(error_appear === "false") {
        extractDetalisFromDB();
        console.log(currentUserName + ' ' + currentUserEmail);  // This is undefined
        var newPostJson = { writer: currentUserEmail, title: title.value, artist: artist.value,            
                           albumOrSong: albumSong.value, content: content.value, genre: 
                           genre.value};        

        $.post(URLAddress + '/addPost', newPostJson).done(function(data) {});
        window.location = '#index';
    }
}
```

The problem is:

The console log and the data I send to the server is always undefined because it happens before the callback functions that retrieves that data from the SQLite ends.

How should I refactor my code so that the extraction from the db will end and only then will the data be sent to the server?
I looked up this problem but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in JavaScript given it's synchronous nature. The recommended solution is to pass a callback into the asynchronous method and trigger that on a success.

So looking at your code you could rework it to look like

```
function extractDetailsFromDB(callback) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM currentUser WHERE id=1', [], function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            currentUserName = results.rows.item(0).name;
            currentUserEmail = results.rows.item(0).data;
            callback();
        }, onError);
    }, errorCb);
}
...
extractDetailsFromDb(function() {
    console.log(currentUserName + ' ' + currentUserEmail);  // This is undefined
    var newPostJson = { writer: currentUserEmail, title: title.value, artist: artist.value,            
                       albumOrSong: albumSong.value, content: content.value, genre: 
                       genre.value};        

    $.post(URLAddress + '/addPost', newPostJson).done(function(data) {});
    window.location = '#index';
});
```

Comment: THNAK YOU!!!! That worked like a charm!
btw It's actually kinda cool the whole callback function thing. A bit weird for me, but cool :)

Comment: @elmekiesIsrael the V8 engine is optimized for throughput hence it doesn't encourage blocking execution or waiting on methods to finish, using callbacks are the more natural solution to that problem.